# Getting a c++11 library on an older version of c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, random

A remote machine that I don't own uses gcc 4.1.2 (2007 or so). I'd like to use the random library and its functions, which comes with the c++11 standard. Is there some way I can use the contents of ? Can I dump all of  into a custom header?

I lack understanding of libraries and wonder if there's a reasonable workaround for this situation.

Comment: Have you looked into `<tr1/random>`? Or [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_random.html)? Since `<random>` was introduced in C++11, there's nothing stopping libstdc++ developers from using C++11 code in the library, so copying the contents into your own file is very unlikely to work. To add to that, things like `random_device` probably are not header only, so you'll need some library to link to as well.

Comment: Boost is definitely the way to go here. My company doesn't have C++11 and we just extensively use the boost libraries which pretty much do what the new standard libraries do

Comment: Thanks for the helpful responses. I will give Boost a shot.